# can't get Variable value of groups of ttk.CheckButtons

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

I'm creating 3 groups of ttk.CheckButtons, using a class clsGrpCheckButton.
The problem is that I can access only the status of the last group created, and not for the previous group.

When clicking on one of the checkButtons of any group, I'm expecting to get the list of checkbuttons check in the group (by using method chkGrpGetValue with is the command parameter of each checkbutton)

However, whatever which button is clicked, the method only and always returns the status of the last group

Here is the code to recreate the issue, and in attachment a picture that shows the problems

Thks for your help.
Rgds

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd

class clsGrpCheckButton(ttk.Checkbutton):
    def __init__(self,pContainer, pLstVal,pCommand,pInitValue=True): 

        self.grpChk=[0]*len(pLstVal)   
        self.grpKey=[0]*len(pLstVal)
        self.grpLstVal = [0]*len(pLstVal)
        self.grpVariable= [0]*len(pLstVal)
        self.grpActiveKeys = [0]

        for l,t in enumerate(pLstVal):
            #l : index of the list of tuples
            self.grpKey[l] = t[0]
            self.grpLstVal[l] = t[1]
            self.grpVariable[l] = tk.StringVar()
            self.grpChk[l] = ttk.Checkbutton(pContainer, text=self.grpLstVal[l],
                                   state='active' ,
                                   onvalue= self.grpKey[l], 
                                   offvalue= '', 
                                   variable =  self.grpVariable[l], 
                                   command=pCommand)

            #get default value
            if pInitValue :
                self.grpVariable[l].set(self.grpKey[l])
                self.grpActiveKeys.append(self.grpKey[l]) 

    #get the index in the list of checkboxes
    # depending on the key
    def chkGrpGetIdx(self, pKey):
        i=0
        while i <len(self.grpKey):
            if self.grpKey[i]==pKey :
                return i
                i=len(self.grpKey)
            else:
                i+=1

    def chkGrpSetValue(self, pKey, pValue):
        #need find correct index first
        i=self.chkGrpGetIdx(pKey)
        self.grpVariable[i] = pValue

    #return the list of keys of the group
    def chkGrpKeyLst(self):
        return self.grpKey

    #return the checkox element of the group of checkox
    def chkGrpGetChkObj(self,pKey):
        i=self.chkGrpGetIdx(pKey)
        return self.grpChk[i]

    #action when check/uncheck
    #at list one element should be active
    def chkGrpGetValue(self):
        i=0
        r=len(self.grpVariable)
        self.grpActiveKeys.clear()
        while i < len(self.grpVariable):

            if self.grpVariable[i].get() =='':
                r-=1
            else:
                self.grpActiveKeys.append(self.grpKey[i])
            i+=1         
        if r==0:
            self.grpVariable[0].set(self.grpKey[0])
            self.grpActiveKeys.append(self.grpKey[0])
        print(self.grpActiveKeys)
    #to avoid accessing to class attribute directly
    def chkGetCheckedValues(self):
        return self.grpActiveKeys


class clsWindows(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self): 
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        la = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
        lb= [10,11,12,14,15,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,30,31,32,33]
        lc=['d10','d11','d12','d14','d15','d20','d21','d22','d23','d24','d25','d26','d30','d31','d32','d33']

        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'DIVISION': la,
             'DEPT_CODE': lb,
             'DEPT_NAME': lc
             })      

        lW = list(zip(df['DIVISION'].astype(str) , df['DEPT_CODE'].astype(str)))
        lpt = list(zip(df['DEPT_CODE'].astype(str) , df['DEPT_NAME'].astype(str)))
        curHead = ""
        r=0
        c=-1
        for head, DPT in lW: 
            if not curHead==head:
                curHead = head
                c+=1
                r=0      
                dq=df.query('DIVISION=='+head)
                lpt = list(zip(dq['DEPT_CODE'].astype(str) , dq['DEPT_NAME'].astype(str)))  
                t=ttk.Labelframe(self,text=head)
                t.grid(column=c, row=0, sticky='nw') 
                self.checkGrpDept= clsGrpCheckButton(t,lpt,lambda:self.checkGrpDept.chkGrpGetValue(),True)                    
            self.checkGrpDept.chkGrpGetChkObj(DPT).grid(column=c, row=r, sticky='nw')
            t.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
            t.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
            r+=1

    def wQuit(self):
        self.destroy()           

app = clsWindows()
app.mainloop()
```

[Example of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZcGr.png)

Comment: Can you indent your code properly?

Comment: dear, done sorry.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It is hard to understand your question without it, and makes it unlikely to be helpful anyone but you.

Comment: edited. Code is still 'long' because of the class, as my assumption is that there is somethong wrong in the class

Answer (score 1):

finally, I came up with a solution by using partial when assigning the command to each checkbutton.
Here is the full code if someone faces a similar issue

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
from functools import partial

class clsGrpCheckButton():
    def __init__(self,pContainer, pLstVal,pCommand,pInitValue=True): 

        self.grpChk=[0]*len(pLstVal)   
        self.grpKey=[0]*len(pLstVal)
        self.grpLstVal = [0]*len(pLstVal)
        self.grpVariable= [0]*len(pLstVal)
        self.grpActiveKeys = [0]

        for l,t in enumerate(pLstVal):
            #l : index of the list of tuples
            self.grpKey[l] = t[0]
            self.grpLstVal[l] = t[1]
            self.grpVariable[l] = tk.StringVar()
            self.grpChk[l] = ttk.Checkbutton(pContainer, text=self.grpLstVal[l],
                                   state='active' ,
                                   onvalue= self.grpKey[l], 
                                   offvalue= '', 
                                   variable =  self.grpVariable[l], 
                                   command=partial(pCommand,self))

            #get default value
            if pInitValue :
                self.grpVariable[l].set(self.grpKey[l])
                self.grpActiveKeys.append(self.grpKey[l]) 

    #get the index in the list of checkboxes
    # depending on the key
    def chkGrpGetIdx(self, pKey):
        i=0
        while i <len(self.grpKey):
            if self.grpKey[i]==pKey :
                return i
                i=len(self.grpKey)
            else:
                i+=1

    def chkGrpSetValue(self, pKey, pValue):
        #need find correct index first
        i=self.chkGrpGetIdx(pKey)
        self.grpVariable[i] = pValue

    #return the list of keys of the group
    def chkGrpKeyLst(self):
        return self.grpKey

    #return the checkox element of the group of checkox
    def chkGrpGetChkObj(self,pKey):
        i=self.chkGrpGetIdx(pKey)
        return self.grpChk[i]

    #action when check/uncheck
    #at list one element should be active
    def chkGrpGetValue(self):
        i=0
        r=len(self.grpVariable)
        self.grpActiveKeys.clear()
        while i < len(self.grpVariable):

            if self.grpVariable[i].get() =='':
                r-=1
            else:
                self.grpActiveKeys.append(self.grpKey[i])
            i+=1         
        if r==0:
            self.grpVariable[0].set(self.grpKey[0])
            self.grpActiveKeys.append(self.grpKey[0])
        print(self.grpActiveKeys)
    #to avoid accessing to class attribute directly
    def chkGetCheckedValues(self):
        return self.grpActiveKeys


class clsWindows(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self): 
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        la = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
        lb= [10,11,12,14,15,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,30,31,32,33]
        lc=['d10','d11','d12','d14','d15','d20','d21','d22','d23','d24','d25','d26','d30','d31','d32','d33']

        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'DIVISION': la,
             'DEPT_CODE': lb,
             'DEPT_NAME': lc
             })      

        lW = list(zip(df['DIVISION'].astype(str) , df['DEPT_CODE'].astype(str)))
        lpt = list(zip(df['DEPT_CODE'].astype(str) , df['DEPT_NAME'].astype(str)))
        curHead = ""
        r=0
        c=-1
        for head, DPT in lW: 
            if not curHead==head:
                curHead = head
                c+=1
                r=0      
                dq=df.query('DIVISION=='+head)
                lpt = list(zip(dq['DEPT_CODE'].astype(str) , dq['DEPT_NAME'].astype(str)))  
                t=ttk.Labelframe(self,text=head)
                t.grid(column=c, row=0, sticky='nw') 
                checkGrpDept= clsGrpCheckButton(t,lpt,clsGrpCheckButton.chkGrpGetValue,True)                    
            checkGrpDept.chkGrpGetChkObj(DPT).grid(column=c, row=r, sticky='nw')
            t.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
            t.columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
            r+=1

    def wQuit(self):
        self.destroy()           

app = clsWindows()
app.mainloop()
```